# This Apple ID has been disabled for security reasons -- more info?

Tags: security, apple-id, password

I recently got a "This Apple ID has been disabled for security reasons" message on all my apple devices. I've have since performed the obligatory password reset process and everything seems to be in working order again.

**I'm very curious as to why** my account was "disabled for security reasons" and was wondering if there was a way to suss this out. I'd really like to know if any of my email addresses or passwords have been compromised.

According to searches, it seems like one reason this can happen is a lot of failed login attempts. I haven't manually logged in for ages, though. Is there a way to see login attempts to ones account?

It doesn't look like there are any suspect devices that have logged in to my account, or any suspect items in my purchase history (viewed through https://reportaproblem.apple.com/). I don't think my account was actually breached, but more information would be very welcome.

Comment: The only people who can reliably answer this question would be Apple themselves.